How to use coq to prove this firstn and nth question?
Theorem fiset_ref_fact : forall (r r' n : nat) (f f' D g g' h h' : list nat) (b b' : bool),
  length f = n /\ n > 0 /\ r < n /\
  h = firstn r f /\ 
  h' = (app h ((nth r f 0)::nil)) /\ r' = r + 1 -> h' = firstn r' f.

I am trying to use induction but I do not know hot to continue...
firstorder.
  induction r eqn:E. destruct f eqn:E0.  simpl in H. symmetry in H. rewrite H in H0. inversion H0. 
  simpl in H2. rewrite H2 in H4. simpl in H4. rewrite H5. simpl. apply H4. 
  destruct f eqn:E0. simpl in H. symmetry in H. rewrite H in H0. inversion H0.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Do you know how to prove this theorem outside of Coq? Coq won't magically help you do the induction if you don't otherwise know how to do the induction on your own. Perhaps you might consider a different approach? Yes, every result about lists comes down to induction in the end, but the Coq standard library has a lot of canned theorems that you may be able to use (where the induction proof is already done for you).

This isn't a traditional "answer", but rather some (perhaps unsolicited) help on how to clarify the question as suggested by the bot, since you need to be able to ask good questions before you can expect to get good answers, and it may not be obvious for a new user how to go about asking good questions.
The standard that we prefer for questions is the concept of a minimal working example (MWE), which means an example that is as small as possible and which a reader can insert directly into a Coq file to investigate what your question is about. In this case, your theorem is not a MWE, since the terms firstn and nth are undefined (thereby violating the "working" requirement for a MWE). You need to import the appropriate library:
From Coq Require Import List.
Theorem fiset_ref_fact : forall (r r' n : nat) (f f' D g g' h h' : list nat) (b b' : bool),
  length f = n /\ n > 0 /\ r < n /\
  h = firstn r f /\ 
  h' = (app h ((nth r f 0)::nil)) /\ r' = r + 1 -> h' = firstn r' f.

With this correction applied, your example now works (it is a "working example"), but it is still not minimal. Your theorem contains a number of variables (f' D g g' b b') which are not used anywhere in the theorem statement. Removing these variables, we now obtain
From Coq Require Import List.
Theorem fiset_ref_fact : forall (r r' n : nat) (f h h' : list nat),
  length f = n /\ n > 0 /\ r < n /\
  h = firstn r f /\ 
  h' = (app h ((nth r f 0)::nil)) /\ r' = r + 1 -> h' = firstn r' f.

which now qualifies as a MWE.
There is a further modification that I would suggest. In Coq and other proof assistants, the construction P ∧ Q → R is not idiomatic. Instead we prefer P → Q → R which is logically equivalent to P ∧ Q → R but much easier to apply in Coq, since you don't need to construct or destruct conjunctions in order to apply the P → Q → R form. Applying this recommendation, your theorem statement now becomes
From Coq Require Import List.
Theorem fiset_ref_fact : forall (r r' n : nat) (f h h' : list nat),
  length f = n -> n > 0 -> r < n ->
  h = firstn r f ->
    h' = (app h ((nth r f 0)::nil)) -> r' = r + 1 -> h' = firstn r' f.

And now you are ready to work on the actual problem.
